# Simplicial basis in iterated bar construction

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ct.category-theory, simplicial-stuff

Let $G$ be an abelian group and set $A:=\mathbb{Z}G$. We can define a commutative dga Hopf algebra
$$B(A):=\bigoplus_{k \in \mathbb{Z}}\,B_k,$$
where $B_k:=A^{\otimes(k+1)}$. I like to think of the basis elements $(a_0,\dots,a_k) \in B_k \; (a_i \in G)$ as labelled $k$-simplices, so I call this the *simplicial notation*. The product and differential on $B(A)$ are then very intuitive to understand geometrically. However, we can write this basis differently $B(A)$ by setting
$$b_0.[b_1|\dots |b_k]:=(b_0,b_0b_1,\dots,b_0b_1 \dots b_k).$$ People call this the *bar notation*. Obviously we have $(a_0,\dots,a_k)=a_0.[a_0^{-1}a_1|a_1^{-1}a_2|\dots|a_{k-1}^{-1}a_k]$. So far the basics.

Now, we can iterate this construction, so that we obtain another commutative dga Hopf algebra $B^k(A)$ with basis elements in bar notation $\beta_0.[\beta_1|\dots|\beta_k]$, where the $\beta_i$ are basis elements in $B^{k-1}(A)$ (up to normalization) and so on. The formula for multiplication and differential in $B^k(A)$ are known explicitly but I have only seen them for the bar notation. I would like to again understand the construction geometrically. It should be possible to write the basis elements in $B^k(A)$ again in simplicial notation $(\alpha_0,\dots,\alpha_k)$, where the $\alpha_i$ are basis elements of $B^{k-1}(A)$. Naively, $(\alpha_0,\dots,\alpha_k)$ should then be thought of as a $k$-simplex with $(k-1)$-simplices "hidden" in the vertices. If I would only know how to translate between the two notations in $B^k(A)$ I could probably make sense of it geometrically by computing the boundary of $(\alpha_0,\dots,\alpha_k)$. This leads me to the following question (sorry if I wasted your time, I wanted to explain where I'm coming from):

Let $H$ be a commutative dga Hopf algebra (I think I need the Hopf part) and let $B(H)$ be the bar construction. How can we translate between the bar notation and the simplicial notation (if it makes sense... ) in $B(H)$.